# EF - getting data from table gives null value

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to fetch data from a MySQL database using Entity Framework.

Here's my code:

```
public IActionResult GetPersons() {
  using (_context) {
    var p = _context.Persons;
    return Ok(p);
  }
}
```

`_context.Persons` is defined like below in my DbContext:

```
public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

I can see in the MySQL logs, that my app does connect successfully to the server, and that the above query is correct.

However, when I add `.FirstOfDefault` or other LINQ methods, the query is affected.

variable `p` remains `null` for unknown reason...

Comment: What is the type of `_context.Persons;` and what is the "failing" query??

Comment: public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; } in DbContext

Comment: Thank you - and the failing query? Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What do you mean? Each time when I invoke the code, I can see the following query on the server side - "SELECT `p`.`IdPerson`, `p`.`Created`, `p`.`CreatedBy`, `p`.`Modified`, `p`.`ModifiedBy`, `p`.`PersonLabel`, `p`.`PersonName`
FROM `Persons` AS `p`" - the query gives proper result on mysql console.

Comment: Yes, but you're saying a `.FirstOfDefault` is failing with `p` staying as `null` - what is *that* query?

Comment: the same, but with LIMIT 1 at the end - exactly as it should be.

Comment: Can you please add the LINQ query to the question please? `the same` is very subjective

Answer (score -1):

You're missing **.ToList()**

```
public IActionResult GetPersons() {
  using (_context) {
    var p = _context.Persons.ToList();
    return Ok(p);
  }
}
```

**See the basics here: [Querying Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/)**

Comment: the same. SQLNullValueException. I wonder if that is somehow connected to mySQL - before I used MS SQL and it worked with almost the same code.

Comment: What NuGet package are you using for mySQL?

Comment: MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore (8.0.22)

Comment: Thanks a lot, because I managed to solve my problem after your comment. I switched to alternative Pomelo package and as a result I got more precise exception message that I'm trying to cast NULL value of one column (which is Nullable DB side) on the model's attribute.